# How to check user is inactive in the app for more than 60 seconds in Kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, timer

In my kotlin based android application, I have a MainActivity and let assume that I have few fragment lets say fragmentOne and fragmentTwo.
What I need is I want to continuously check if the user is inactive in the application for 60 seconds and If so, I need to show some layout to infor the user that he is inactive. Also the code should run on Main activity and it should listen the fragment activities as well.

What I have added in main activity is given below

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mHandler: Handler
    private lateinit var mRunnable: Runnable
    private var mTime: Long = 60000

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        mRunnable = Runnable {
            Log.d("Checking", "Timer checking  :  User inactive for ${mTime/1000} secs!")
        }
        startHandler()

    }


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        stopHandler()
        startHandler()
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
    private fun startHandler(){
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mTime)
    }

    private fun stopHandler(){
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
    }

}
```

In the above code, The timer checking is done only once. But I need to reset the timer when user is active and the timer should run again repeatedly and check if user is inactive for more than 60 seconds

Not sure why it is not working for me, Is it because of the fragment is only availabe in the view port?

Answer (score 0):

this is my time check code with progress bar. I hope it works for you. Jodatime request for Datetime
When user do something edit lastTimeRequest

```
    val lastTimeRequest = PrivatePreferences(requireContext(), "lastTimeRequest")
    val progressBarPreference = PrivatePreferences(requireContext(), TAG)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {

        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            
            while (true) {

                val leftTimeLong = progressBarPreference.readLong() - DateTime.now().minusSeconds(50).millis
                viewModel.progressBarMutableFlow.emit(leftTimeLong)

                if (lastTimeRequest.readLong() < DateTime.now().minusSeconds(50).millis) {
                    viewModel.callFlow().collect {
                        it?.let {
                            lastTimeRequest.saveLong(DateTime.now().millis)
                            //to it
                        }
                    }
                } 
                delay(1000)
            }
        }
    }
```